# Can I take capital loss here? (Wash sale) And how to calculate cost basis?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-loss, wash-sale

Lets say I have the following trades of CompanyA stock:

```
Jan 1st  - bought 5 for $10
Jan 15th - bought 3 for $12
Jan 25th - bought 3 for $15

Apr 15th - sold 11 for $18 -- Gain

May 5th - Bought 5 for $16 -- Less than a month after I sold all.

May 10th - Bought 5 for $17
```

Now the value of the Stock is $15. (At loss)

1. Can I claim loss here, if I sell all the stocks now?
2. If so, how do I calculate how much I can claim as loss?
3. How do I calculate cost basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shares bought in your first 3 transactions were all sold on Apr 15th for a gain of $67 (+40 +18 +9).

If you were to sell the 5 shares bought  on May 5th for a loss in less than 31 days after  the purchase made on May 10th, that  would create a wash sale violation. Selling them now would not.. But that's not what you asked.   You could sell  the remaining 10 shares  anytime you want.  If sold now at $15 per share, the loss would be $15 and there would be no wash sale violation as long as you waited 31 days before buying these shares again.